# Sorting values in objects by putting order?

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

Saying that there is a list and I add some stuffs in it:

```
list.add(new Stuff("Test1"))
list.add(new Stuff("Test2"))
list.add(new Stuff("Test3"))
list.add(new Stuff("Test4"))
list.add(new Stuff("Test5"))
```

and if I put it in the hashmap like this:

```
private static HashMap<Integer, Report> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

public static void getStuffs(Stuff stuff) {

        int hashCode = stuff.hashCode();

        if (!hashMap.containsKey(hashCode)) {
            hashMap.put(hashCode, stuff);
        }
    }
```

And when I print the values that are stored in the hashMap, the expected output is:

```
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4
Test5
```

But it is actually stored in the hashMap in a strange order.

Could someone please tell me how to solve this problem?

I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead of a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). As you can learn from the documentation also, the main difference between `HashMap` and `LinkedHashMap` is that a `LinkedHashMap` maintains the insertion order of keys (i.e. the order in which keys are inserted into the `LinkedHashMap`) while a `HashMap` does not maintain any order of keys.